# SCRIPT src not loaded after append in to HTML using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am developing application where required to load new HTML and append into current page HTML.

Now, I loaded new HTML using `jQuery ajax` but in new loaded HTML have `<script>` which `display audio to play`. But my issue is when script load then script tag from loaded HTML not display even not loaded.

I used:

```
<script src="Link of JS file which create audio" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Above code not display / not loaded after append.

I append like:

```
var html = '<div> <h1>Header</h1> <div>Contain area</div>
            <script src="Link of JS file which create audio" type="text/javascript"></script></div>'
$("#container").append(html);
```

But not working. Any one have a idea in it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery `getScript();`

```
$.getScript( "url/for/script.js" )
    .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
        console.log( 'script loaded' );
     })
    .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
        console.log( 'Script not loaded' );
     });
```

This will append the JavaScript file in script tags.

Read more [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/).

Comment: Some mis-understanding here. Can you please check updated question now.